# Edit And Delete Div on click and Apply changes in code too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a `div` consisting of `ul` and `li` in it.
Now I want to add `Edit` and `Delete` buttons inside the div, and by clicking the Edit button the div should get editable and it should show two more option `Save` and `Cancel` .

Now the main thing is that after running program, when I `Edit` or `Delete` it should also `change code in Program`.
Is there any way I can do it? Thanks

Comment: Down voters please don't down vote, i am new to programming so may be i am asking something you experienced guys may find foolish.

Comment: have added a jsfiddle for your code, please update incase not correct.

Comment: You want an 1.'Edit and Delete button in div'- which div ?  2.'clicking Edit button div should get editable' - which div ? 3. 'when i Edit or Delete it should also change code in Program' - change code in program ? please clarify these

Comment: Welcome to the site, I think you should learn a bit yourself. I see no attempt to solve the problem. People in this site help you when you get stuck, but don't solve problems from scratch for you.

Comment: @Yasser I have updated JS fiddle, and now when i click on edit whole div should become editable and two option should show up whether to save or cancel changes. Change code in program means, it changes made during runtime should be updated in original code

Comment: @Yasser This complete div <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">

Comment: @Martin i was able to edit li, but don't know how to make div editable. :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are trying to say by "make div editable". Try to define "editable" or rephrase this. At the end of the day, you want to be able to click the 'edit' change the text, and then click 'save'?

Comment: @Martin that is what exactly i want, when Edit button is clicked,i should be able to make changes to text and also have a save option which can save after changes are made.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this** [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MMzYJ/6/)
I have added jQuery and tried to meet your requirement

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#edit').click(function(){
     document.getElementById("collapseOne").contentEditable="true";
     $('#collapseOne').attr('style','border:2px solid;');
     $('#edit').attr('style','display:none;');
     $('#done').attr('style','display:block;');
   });

   $('#done').click(function(){
     document.getElementById("collapseOne").contentEditable="false";
     $('#collapseOne').attr('style','border:none;');
     $('#edit').attr('style','display:block;');
     $('#done').attr('style','display:none;');
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">
        We are hiring!
    </h1>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                       href="#collapseOne">
                        .Net Developer  : Posted on 24th Feb
                    </a> 
                    <a href='#' style="float:right" id="edit">Edit</a>  
                    <a href='#' style="display:none;" id="done">Done</a>
                    <a href='#' style="float:center;margin-left:100px;">Delete</a>
                </h4>  

            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                <p class="lead justified">
                    Qualifications and Skills:
                </p>
                <ul class="fa-ul">
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa"></i><span class="lead justified"> BE experience </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa"></i><span class="lead justified"> Solid skills </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa"></i><span class="lead justified"> Strong understanding </span><a>Delete</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa"></i><span class="lead justified"> Sharp analytical </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa"></i><span class="lead justified"> Ability to effectively </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa"></i><span class="lead justified"> Deal </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa"></i><span class="lead justified"> Strong sense of ownership, urgency, and drive</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa"></i><span class="lead justified"> Excellent </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works good. Now i just need to save edited changes to original code as well.Is it possible??Voting up for this ans :)

Comment: Make one ajax request on click of DONE and save the contains. (http://jsfiddle.net/MMzYJ/7/)

Don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: I am not to familiar with AJAX, will you please help me out with it. Thanks

Comment: Saving data or changes in what? Language/DB and other constraints are required.You can read about jQuery Ajax and then try to implement the functionality. Question you have asked doesn't state anywhere about saving edited contains

Comment: I would have help you more if you provide above details like Language/DB Link where you will process etc

Comment: I have written in ques Apply changes in code too.Is it possible to Append changes to above HTML code ???

Comment: I will try it out using AJAX,will you help me out in deleting div on click.Thanks:)

Comment: Do want to delete entire div contain?

Comment: Yes,because if want to delete some li i can do it in editing right??

Comment: Thanks a lot,Voting up for all your answers. Any help with AJAX will be great.Thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mainly stuck with how to make your `div` containing the `li` and `ul` elements editable. For that, you need to use the contentEditable property of the div element.

You can use JavaScript to enable this property from the Edit button.

You could use this JavaScript code to enable the property:

```
 onclick='document.getElementById("collapseOne").contentEditable="true";'
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMzYJ/4/) for the same.

Comment: Not exactly what i am looking for, on Edit click it should show textarea on complete div and then i should be able to edit it,after editing i should also be able to save changes. Still voting you up :) Thanks

Comment: HTML textareas do not support rich formatting or bullet points, so you would lose all of your formatting that way.